# Laravel built in Authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

In a Laravel built in authentication, among the many available classes and interfaces, I have narrowed it down to `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth` and `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard`as am trying to figure out how the authentication works, can anyone please explain to me the principle or just how these two correlates such that am able to call `Auth::check()` or any of the related functions which are implemented by `Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard` but not with
`Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth`. Thanks in advance.

**P.S.** Am trying to build my own custom authentication in laravel and i just want to understand this one.

Comment: The Facades use a [magic method](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.callstatic) of PHP. You can read the [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/facades#how-facades-work) about how the Facades work. You can see it 'in action' [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php#L213).

Comment: All the classes can be found here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/5.4/src/Illuminate/Auth

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: Facades are perfect for it.